# Cant use .get() from Entry field, python3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I just want to create a program, so that when I click the "Print" Button, it takes data from an entry field and outputs to a text field below. Is there something wrong with my usage of `.get()`? Not exactly sure what's the problem?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

wd=tk.Tk()

def inkq():
    string= str(nd.get())
    ketqua.insert(END, string)

nd=Entry(wd).pack()
btn=Button(wd, text ="Print", command = inkq).pack()
btn1=Button(wd, text ="Quit", command = wd.destroy).pack()
ketqua=Text(wd, height =10, width = 40).pack()

wd.mainloop()
```

Comment: You didn't say what was wrong. What happens?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that .pack() returns None, which does not have a get method.
Which can be seen in the following error print from when I ran your code.

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

wd=tk.Tk()

def inkq():
    string= str(nd.get())
    ketqua.insert(END, string)
nd=Entry(wd) #Save entry befor packing
nd.pack()

btn=Button(wd, text ="Print", command = inkq).pack()
btn1=Button(wd, text ="Quit", command = wd.destroy).pack() 
ketqua=Text(wd, height =10, width = 40) #Save entry before packing
ketqua.pack()

wd.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tks you very much, it make me headache lot.